# Unity EditorWindow - Toggle Gameobject from Window

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I've used Unity for quite some time, but never tried the editor. Today I decided to try to make an EditorWindow to help me with shortcuts with my development.

What I want is to click on a button on my Window to turn on and off a specific light in my scene.

Added the code and an image of the Window below.

I am clueless on how to proceed. Any help would be appreciated a lot!

```
public class DevTools : EditorWindow
{
    public Object workLight;

    [MenuItem("Window/DevTools")]
    public static void ShowWindow()
    {
        GetWindow<DevTools>("Development Tools");
    }

    private void OnGUI()
    {
        GUILayout.Label("This is the development tools.", EditorStyles.boldLabel);

        workLight = EditorGUILayout.ObjectField(workLight, typeof(object), true);

        if (GUILayout.Button("Working Light"))
        {
            if(workLight == null)
            {
                ShowNotification(new GUIContent("No light selected"));
            }
            else
            {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

[This is my current Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WRH2L.png)

Comment: Please put the code IN the question

Comment: You need to cast the `workLight` object to a an actual `Light ` or whatever the equivalent type is in Unity, that way you can access properties/methods of the light and call the appropriate method - just looking at docs it looks like since all objects are GameObject instances you need to grab the `Light` component off the instance using `GetComponent<Light>()` - shouldn't your `workLight` be of type `GameObject`? If not, I assume you can just cast anyway and then use `GetComponent`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks a lot Charleh!

With a little bit of rewriting, this seem to work. Not sure if it is optimized perfectly, but it works without a hitch (atm) :p.

```
public class DevTools : EditorWindow
{
    Object workLight = default;

    [MenuItem("Window/DevTools")]
    public static void ShowWindow()
    {
        GetWindow<DevTools>("Development Tools");
    }
    private void OnGUI()
    {
        GUILayout.Label("This is the development tools.", EditorStyles.boldLabel);
        if (GUILayout.Button("Working Light"))
        {
            if (workLight == null)
            {
                ShowNotification(new GUIContent("No light selected"));
            }
            else
            {
                var light = GameObject.Find("Work Light");
                if (light == null)
                {
                    ShowNotification(new GUIContent("Selected object is not a light"));
                    return;
                }
                else
                {
                    light.gameObject.GetComponent<Light>().enabled = !light.gameObject.GetComponent<Light>().enabled;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is only going to work for one light in your scene and won't work if the light is inactive. Looking at `GameObject.Find` in docs shows this `This function only returns active GameObjects. If no GameObject with name can be found, null is returned. If name contains a '/' character, it traverses the hierarchy like a path name.`. Not sure on object naming either - I assume that you have more than one light and you will only be able to toggle one light with this code (the one named Work Light`)

Comment: Also, there's no point in having a GUI selector on your window if you aren't going to use the variable it's connected to - you are ignoring the `workLight` variable and using `GameObject.Find` which is going to find the same object every time no matter which light you select in the scene.

Comment: This is just an directional Light that gives my entire scene light. So I just have one. :)

Comment: There's no point in having `workLight = EditorGUILayout.ObjectField(workLight, typeof(object), true);` or the `workLight` variable then since that's supposed to be there so you can select an object in your scene so you can do something with it. If you only have one light then you should be OK assuming you don't overwrite the previous result of `GameObject.Find` each time you click the button - the docs state that trying to find an inactive object will return null so I'm not sure how this can be working?

Comment: `if (GUILayout.Button("Working Light"))
        {
            var light = GameObject.Find("Work Light");

            var lighting = light.gameObject.GetComponent<Light>();

            if (light == null)
            {
                ShowNotification(new GUIContent("Selected object is not a light"));
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                lighting.enabled = !lighting.enabled;
            }
            
        }`
Yes I shortened the whole button down to this.

Comment: There's no point in doing the null check on the `light` variable since it will never be null plus you are checking the wrong variable anyway. Might as well just be `var light = GameObject.Find("Work Light"); light.GetComponent<Light>().enabled = !light.GetComponent<Light>().enabled`... save yourself some lines!

Comment: Just did that now! Thanks a lot man, that went from a big code to a small one very quickly. :p

Comment: Well, now you know how to make things selectable in a box so you can make tools for your own custom stuff on your GameObject instances (if for example you design your own game components or plugins at some point)

Answer (score 0):

Well, you need a reference to the object to proceed with turning it on and off. You can either add a field to the editor and manually choose the object from the scene or dynamically find it through GameObject.Find.

Comment: Where would I put the `GameObject.Find`? 
I just tried a  `workLight.gameObject.SetActive(true);` in my else statement. After putting the `GameObject.Find("Work Light");` above.

I am all new to this editor coding, so have no idea on how to structure it.

Comment: I don't think you need this - I believe the editor box in the GUI allows you to select an object when you click on it? If so, you already have an instance of the game object in the `worklight` variable at the point of clicking the button

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know Unity (never used it) but it looks pretty straightforward.

The `EditorFieldForObject` method seems to take a second type param that denotes which types you can select using the field in the GUI - I'm not sure if you can make this a `GameObject` or not, but there are basically two approaches that should work:

Leave your code as is and cast the object (in `OnGUI` method):

```
var gameObject = workLight as GameObject;

if(gameObject == null)
{
    ShowNotification(new GUIContent("No light selected"));
}
else
{
    var light = gameObject.GetComponent<Light>();

    if(light == null) 
    {
        ShowNotification(new GUIContent("Selected object is not a light"));
        return;
    }

    // Not sure if this is the correct way to disable a light but you can figure it out
    light.enabled = false;
    // or light.enabled = !light.enabled to toggle state
}
```

The other way is to make the editor GUI box look for GameObject instances in the first place:

```
public GameObject workLight;
....
workLight = EditorGUILayout.ObjectField(workLight, typeof(GameObject), true);
```

But I'm not sure if this is possible or not (as I've said, I don't know Unity)

**Edit:** apparently you need to use `GameObject.SetActive(boolean)` to toggle the 
state of an object

Since you want to toggle, you can use the `GameObject.activeSelf` field which gives you the active true/false flag on the current object

So this should work:

```
light.SetActive(!light.activeSelf);
```

Comment: Apperently this works now if I do `light.SetActive(false);`in the else, but I want it to toggle every time I hit the button.

Comment: Try `light.SetActive(!light.activeSelf)` - I think `activeSelf` tells you if the object is active or not based on the docs here: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject-activeSelf.html

Comment: So I am experiencing the same thing, I can turn of the light alright. But it gives me a null reference when the light is Null.
 I tried 
`var light =GameObject.Find("Work Light");` and `var light = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("WorkLight");`
They both give the null reference when trying to turn it back on.

Comment: You don't need to find the `GameObject` if I understand correctly - the box you have added above the button allows you to click it and then choose an object in your scene (or maybe you select an object in your scene and this box is filled in automatically). If so, you already have an instance of your game object in the `workLight` variable in your original code. You don't need to find the game object because the GUI has already filled that variable with a reference to the object for you. You just need to try to cast and it should work. If you use the exact code I posted it should work.

Comment: If you look at the example code here: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorGUILayout.ObjectField.html you can see that they do not use `GameObject.Find` and just respond to the `OnGUI` event assuming that either `source == null` (in which case nothing is selected) or the other boolean outcome (something has been selected). They directly operate on `source` without needing the `Find`